# Laravel error "Trying to get property of non-object" when inside an if() condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It's strange, I can access the property before the if statement, and if I change the if condition to something else, I can accessible the property inside the if statement as well. But trying to access the property inside the if condition throws an error:

```
$market_ids = [];
$state->cities->each(function($city) use (&$market_ids)
{
      dd($city->market->id);  // <-Accessible here

      if (!in_array($city->market->id, $market_ids)){ // Error: Trying to get property of non-object

         dd($city->market->id); // Accessible here
         $market_ids[] = $city->market->id;

      }
});
```

Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Which PHP-Version do you run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should make sure that for each of your cities your relation doesn't return `null`:

```
$market_ids = [];
$state->cities->each(function($city) use (&$market_ids)
{

       if ($city->market === null) {
         echo " null market for ".$city->name."<br />";
         continue;
       } 


      if (!in_array($city->market->id, $market_ids)){ 

         $market_ids[] = $city->market->id;

      }
});
```

As you used `dd` you checked it for first record and it doesn't mean that for 2nd or 3rd or later rows there's corresponding market object. For example you have 100 cities and 99 nine of them have market and one of them doesn't. You will get the error you asked because for one of them you don't have market so you cannot ask for market id.

So to make it clear this error is rather not connected to `if` or `in_array`, because if you use:

```
$market_ids = [];
$state->cities->each(function($city) use (&$market_ids)
{
      echo $city->market->id; // not dd but simply echo
});
```

you will probably also get the same error.

Comment: Thank you Marcin! This was the exact problem. One of my cities did not have a market.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   means the source `$city->market` not an object in some cases, or check this edit:

```
$market_ids = [];
$state->cities->each(function($city) use (&$market_ids)
{
      $id = $city->market->id;

      dd($id);

      if ( ! in_array($id, $market_ids) ){ 

         dd($id);
         $market_ids[] = $id;

      }
});
```

Comment: Outside of the if condition it is an object. For example, the first dd() I've illustrated.

Comment: try to get the ``$city->market->id`` in separated var ``$id`` then use it , then check what will happen